# changing defaultroute in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am very new to cakephp.

I have my project 'registration' in the **workspace**. I have created an IndexController, which contains method index().

When I run my project by using workspace/registration/ it displays the following error:

```
Error: WorkspaceController could not be found. Create the class WorkspaceController below in file: app/Controller/WorkspaceController.php.
```

I want to exicute IndexController first. Somebody advised me to change the default route. But I dont know how to change the route. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP has a fantastic documentation -> [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html)

And to your question, did you try to do what they suggested? Creating the class WorkspaceController in Controller!

Comment: Did you read the cookbook? They describe how to change the default route.

Answer (score 0):

In `app/Config/routes.php`:

```
Router::connect(
    '/workspace/registration',
    array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index')
);
```

If `/workspace/registration` is where you register to join a workspace, though, I'd really recommend creating a `WorkspaceController` to deal with all workspace-related functionality.

Work *with* the default routes, not against them, it will make your life a lot easier.